# Transform rotate() not working correctly

Tags: css, css-transforms

I can't figure it out why the css transform: rotate() not working.
Here's the code: http://jsbin.com/afayan/1/edit
When I put a background color to class "content", the transform is not working...

Comment: works for me in Chrome... and FF...and safari... doesn't work in IE9 though. Is that your question?

Comment: it's not working because of `z-index:-1`, do you really need it?

Comment: -ms- is missing in the code to work in IE9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must add the proper z-index for both contents. Or remove the z-index.

Updated:

[Code](http://jsbin.com/afayan/14/edit)

Comment: But when i do that, the red div comes first - i want it to be in the back - only to see it at the corners.

Comment: No problem. I changed the code in my answer so accept it if You are pleased with it. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is about z-indexes. Try this:

```
.content { padding:50px; background: green; z-index: 5; }
.box { background:#ccc; padding:50px; position:relative;}
.box:after { content:''; width:100%; height:100%; left:0; top:0; 
             background:red; position:absolute; z-index:4; 
             -moz-transform: rotate(2deg); transform: rotate(2deg); 
             -webkit-transform: rotate(2deg); }
```

Comment: That's why i used the z-index with -1, to put it behind, and works  only if i don't have a background. But i want to have a background...